Caculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}-1}{x}$
Caculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}-1}{x}$
Here is what I tried:
By using L'Hospital theory:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{(\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}-1)'}{(x)'}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{k\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}}{1+k^2x}=k$$
with $(f(x))'=\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)$
Is this correct? Thank you a lot for any help!!

I have fixed, sorry for my typo

Well, strictly speaking, invoking H's rule is circular reasoning, here, because the limit you are trying to evaluate is the actual derivative that you 'invoke' to evaluate it. But! Be that as it may, the tag for the question is 'algebra-PREcalculus.' Are you allowed derivatives = "calculus"  ?

Thanks for your assistance @YvesDaoust !!!

Sorry my English is not good, can you say more easier for me please @peterag, thanks.

We will use a series expansion :
$$ \underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}
-1}{x}= \underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} \frac{1+\frac{1}{k} \times k^2x-1 + o(x)}{x}=\underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\text{lim}} ~ k + o(1) = k$$

@peterag Oh my bad, you are right !

What is $o(x)$, thanks.

@LụcTrườngPhát $o(x)$ is a function that is negligible compared to $x$. In our case, it means that when $x \rightarrow 0,~\frac{o(x)}{x} \rightarrow 0$

Another way, for example without derivative, to use that $\sqrt[m]{1+y}-1 \sim \frac{y}{m}, y\to 0$, so we obtain
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}-1}{x} \cdot \frac{k^2x}{k^2x}= \frac{1}{k}\cdot k^2=k$$
so, your result is correct.

This is a comment, but too long for that section. The aim is to explain why Hospital's rule is a bit suspicious here.
Suppose the question was to evaluate $$L= \lim_{x \to 0} {\sin x \over x}.$$
(The answer is $1$, of course.)
The temptation is to use H's rule:
$$L =  {\sin'(0) \over 1} = {\cos 0 \over 1}.$$
But! By definition, $$ \sin' (0) =\lim_{h \to 0} {\sin h - \sin 0\over h} = \lim_{h \to 0} {\sin h - 0 \over h} = \lim_{h \to 0} {\sin h \over h}.$$
You see? The derivative is exactly the limit we were supposed to evaluate. Probably the argument that you know that $\sin' x = \cos x$ depends on knowing the above limit.
Hope that helps....

Also note that by $f(x)=\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}$ without l'Hospital by the definition of derivative we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}-1}{x}= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)=k$$

this was the point of my 'This is a comment' answer...

@peterag Oh yes I see now! That's precisely the idea indeed

As an alternative by standard limits $\frac{e^x-1}{x} \to 1$ and $\frac{\log(1+x)}{x} \to 1$ we have
$$\frac{\sqrt[k]{1+k^2x}-1}{x}=\frac{e^{\frac{\log(1+k^2x)}{k}}-1}{\frac{\log(1+k^2x)}{k}}\cdot \frac{\log(1+k^2x)}{k^2x}\cdot k \to 1 \cdot 1\cdot k =k$$

Without making the things complicated by taking derivative we can solve it easily,
$$
L:=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[k]{1 + k^2x} - 1}{x}
$$
Substitute $ y := 1 + k^2x $ which implies $ x = \frac{y - 1}{k^2} $:
$$\begin{align*}
 L&=\lim_{y \to 1} k^2\cdot\frac{y^{1/k} - 1^{1/k}}{y-1}\\
&=k^2.\frac{1}k\\ &= k\quad \left[\because\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{x^{n}-a^{n}}{x-a} =n\: a^{(n-1)}\right]\\
\end{align*}
$$
